# Get records with value of XML node with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

Using XPath and given the following XML I can find all records that =

```
strXpath = "//pub-code/ad-type[class-code='XX Cls Employment']" (works)
Set nlAds = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes(strXPath)
```

How can I get all records that =

```
strXpath = "//pub-code[ad-type='XX Cls Display']" (doesn't work)?
Set nlAds = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes(strXPath)
```

The second XPath only works if the tags are on the same line.

I am obviously missing something. I have spent hours trying many different recommendations but none seem to work.

```
<web-export>
<run-date>11/08/2015
<pub-code>XX Domain.com
<ad-type>XX Cls Display
<cat-code>Employment</cat-code>
<class-code>XX Cls Employment</class-code>
<ad-number>00000123456</ad-number>
</ad-type>
</pub-code>
</run-date>
</web-export>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably that the text node spans up to the next line, so it does not equal the string you're searching for.

Prune the text before

```
//pub-code[normalize-space(ad-type/text()) = 'XX Cls Display']
```

or test whether the string is contained:

```
//pub-code[contains(ad-type/text(), 'XX Cls Display')]
```

Comment: Thank you.  These are the answers I find when I search, but I have not been able to get them to work in my example.

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) how exactly you query the document, both containing the input and code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
//pub-code[normalize-space(ad-type/text())='XX Cls Display']
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this and it still doesn't select anything.

Comment: This is because different implementations handle whitespace differently. You should always post what your software stack is.

Comment: I am writing VBscript.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `//pub-code[ad-type[starts-with(., 'XX Cls Display')]]` or `//pub-code[ad-type[contains(., 'XX Cls Display')]]`. See http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYia.

Comment: Thanks, it still returns 0 nodes.

Comment: I am using "Microsoft.XMLDOM" in a VBScript on a Windows 2008 Server.  It works fine as long as the start and end tags are on the same line.  If the tags are broken up by new line character it does not work.  I have been trying for hours.